# SVG - create path for textpath dynamically?

Tags: svg, text

I want to have a curved text along a path (half circle) in SVG. I have followed this tutorial, which is great: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/svg/curved-text-along-path/

The problem is that the path presented there works only for this specific text - `Dangerous Curves Ahead`. If you leave only `Dangerous` word that's what happens: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pqqVGa - it no longer works (the text is no more evenly spreaded across the path).

I want to have it work regardless of text length. How to achieve that?

Comment: The text isn't evenly spread across the path in the original example either, it's just that the font and the number of words fairly closely match the path length. You could increse the font size till it matched the path length if you wrote some javascript code to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is assuming that the initial text size (35) is too small.

```js
let curveLength = curve.getTotalLength();
let fs = 35;//the initial font size
test.setAttributeNS(null, "style", `font-size:${fs}px`)
while(test.getComputedTextLength() < curveLength){
  fs++
  test.setAttributeNS(null, "style", `font-size:${fs}px`)
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

text {
  fill: #FF9800;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <path id="curve" d="M73.2,148.6c4-6.1,65.5-96.8,178.6-95.6c111.3,1.2,170.8,90.3,175.1,97" />
    <text id="test">
      <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
        Dangerous
      </textPath>
      </text>
  </svg>
```

#### UPDATE

The OP is commenting:

> Thanks for the response. Instead of adjusting the font size, I would prefer to create a new path that is longer / smaller and matches the text width. Not sure how to do this tho. – feerlay

Please read the comments in the code. In base of the length of the text I'm calculating the new path, but I'm assuming a lot of things: I'm assuming the new path starts in the same point as the old one.

```js
let textLength = test.getComputedTextLength();
// the center of the black circle
let c = {x:250,y:266}
// radius of the black circle
let r = 211;
// the black arc starts at point p1
let p1 = {x:73.2,y:150}
// the black arc ends at point p2
let p2 = {x:426.8,y:150}
// distance between p1 and p2
let d = dist(p1, p2);
// the angle of the are begining at p1 and ending at p2
let angle = Math.asin(.5*d/r);

// the radius of the new circle
let newR = textLength / angle; 
// the distance between p1 and the new p2
let newD = 2 * Math.sin(angle/2) * newR;
// the new attribute c for the path #curve
let D = `M${p1.x},${p1.y} A`
D += `${newR}, ${newR} 0 0 1 ${p1.x + newD},${p1.y} `
document.querySelector("#curve").setAttributeNS(null,"d",D);
// a function to calculate the distance between two points
function dist(p1, p2) {
  let dx = p2.x - p1.x;
  let dy = p2.y - p1.y;
  return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

text {
  fill: #FF9800;
};
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <path id="black_circle" d="M73.2,148.6c4-6.1,65.5-96.8,178.6-95.6c111.3,1.2,170.8,90.3,175.1,97" />
  
  <path id ="curve"  d="M73.2,150 A 211,211 0 0 1 426.8,150" fill="#777" />
    <text id="test">
      <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
        Dangerous curves
      </textPath>
      </text>

  
  </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Instead of adjusting the font size, I would prefer to create a new path that is longer / smaller and matches the text width. Not sure how to do this tho.

Comment: Thank you once again - that is really helpful! Looks like you are pretty good at math :)

Answer (score 3):

Using the attributes [lengthAdjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/lengthAdjust) and  [textLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/textLength) you can adjust the length of the text and the height of the letters, thereby placing the text of the desired length on a segment of a fixed length

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="500" height="300" viewBox="0 0 500 300">  

<path id="path1" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M30,151 Q215,21 443,152 " /> 

<text id="txt1" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="400" font-size="24">
<textPath id="result" method="align" spacing="auto" startOffset="1%" xlink:href="#path1">
<tspan dy="-10"> very long text very long text very long text </tspan>

</textPath>
</text>
 
</svg>
```

Using the attribute `startOffset =" 10% "` you can adjust the position of the first character of the phrase

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="500" height="300" viewBox="0 0 500 300" >  

<path id="path1" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M30,151 Q215,21 443,152 " /> 

<text id="txt1" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="400" font-size="24">
<textPath id="result" method="align" spacing="auto" startOffset="15%" xlink:href="#path1">
<tspan dy="-10"> very long text very long text very long text </tspan>

</textPath>
</text>
 
</svg>
```

and make animation using this attribute (**click canvas**)

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="500" height="300" viewBox="0 0 500 300">  

<path id="path1" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M30,151 Q215,21 443,152 " /> 

<text id="txt1" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" textLength="200" font-size="24">
 <textPath id="result" method="align" spacing="auto" startOffset="-100%" xlink:href="#path1">
    <tspan dy="-10"> Very long text Very long text Very long text </tspan>
  <animate
   begin="svg1.click"
   dur="15s"
   attributeName="startOffset"
   values="-100%;1%;1%;100%;1%;1%;-100%"
   repeatCount="5"/> 
 </textPath>
</text>
 
  <text x="200" y="150" font-size="24" fill="orange" >Click me </text>
 
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! What should I do to have this one working: https://jsfiddle.net/skc4pnyh/ ? :)